# Demoting a subprocess call from running as admin

Tags: python, windows, powershell, subprocess, admin

I'm running a python script through powershell:

```
python.exe script.py
```

powershell is configured to run as Admin on the machine (Windows). Inside the script I'm trying to run `subprocess`:

```
test_process = subprocess.Popen("subscript.exe")
```

What I need for the `"subscript.exe"` process (subprocess) not to run as an admin on the machine, while not stopping the execution of the original script.

Answer (score 0):

If Powershell and python need to run as admin, but you want just the subscript to run with basic user privileges, you can probably do something like this (not sure if you need to add arguments separately):

```
subprocess.Popen('runas /trustlevel:0x20000 subscript.exe')
```

I don't have python on my machine at the moment, but here's what it looks like running a new Powershell process that requires admin permissions for example:

[image: running as user with restricted privilegs]

trust level `0x20000` equates to Basic User, which you can see with `runas /showtrustlevels`. In my case, it's only one available.